# Rails Mongodb can't save record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Mongodb in my Rails app. I have 2 models, which are `Account` and `User`. Account has many users and users belongs to account.

`Account` model

```
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :account, :dependent => :destroy
validates :organization_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

`User` model

```
belongs_to :account, :inverse_of => :users
validates :account, :presence => false
validates :email, presence: true
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

def User.new_token
 SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def self.create_with_password(attr={})
 generated_password = attr[:email] + User.new_token
 self.create!(attr.merge(password: generated_password, password_confirmation: generated_password))
end
```

`User` controller

```
def new
    @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
    @user = @current_user.account.users.new
end

def create
    @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
    @user = @current_user.account.users.create_with_password(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
if @user.save
  format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    format.js
else
  format.html { render 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end

private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :owner, :admin)
    end
```

I can successfully sign up an account with a user. But when I tried to add a new user, the user record can't be saved. I assigned a password for users when creating a new user.

The error messages:

```
message: Validation of User failed. summary: The following errors were found: Account can't be blank resolution: Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

If I removed the self.create_with_password and manually type in the password in the form, it works. So i guess the error must be in the self create password, it seems like doesn't save the record. By the way I'm using Rails 5.0. Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @ternggio Welcome to community.

> Account can't be blank.

This error appear due to `belongs_to` statement in `user.rb`.

In rails > 5 `belongs_to` is by default required, You can set as optional with marking `optional: true`.

```
belongs_to :account, :inverse_of => :users, optional: true
```

and remove below line.

```
validates :account, :presence => false
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: If I remove below this line `validates :account, :presence => false`, the user record is saved successfully but with `account_id = nil`. There is no association between the account and the user.

Comment: above line is useless any way. but account_id is nil due something else reason. make sure account is present at the time of creation account.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by adding `@user.account_id = @current_user.account.id` to the `create` action in the `User` controller because there is an `account_id` attribute in the User table. Then I followed your solution by removing this line `validates :account, :presence => false`, and everything works fine. I wanna give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I'm happy that solution work for you. Have a great day.